# Serverless Framework and multiple AWS profiles

Tags: serverless-framework

I have multiple AWS profiles setup in my credentials file

```
[dev]
aws_key = xx
aws_secret = yy
[qa]
aws_key = aa
aws_secret = bb
[prod]
aws_key = mm
aws_secret = qq
```

When deploying is there anyway to inform the Serverless Framework which credentials to use?

For example:

```
serverless deploy --profile prod
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, the command line option is `--aws-profile`. E.g.:

`serverless deploy --aws-profile prod`

Docs [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/#using-the-aws-profile-option).

Comment: Have you actually gotten this to work?  I never have and there are multiple github issues opened about this not actually working. When I use it, it just ignores what I enter and uses default profile and tells me I don't have permission.  My profile switching works fine for everything else with AWS though.

Comment: @red6 I just tested locally and was able to deploy using the specified account. What version of the Framework are you using locally?

Comment: @1.25.  I found a workaround tool that provides me a one line command to export the right profile to env variables, but using `--aws-profile` never worked.  Lots of comments on the github issues about this.  Are you using one set of credentials with different role profiles?  Or completely different profiles and credentials.  Because I am using roles and one set of credentials, which is how our company operates and works with AWS CLI without issue.

Comment: @red6 Ahh, interesting. I'm using the completely different profiles and credentials. For your setup, are the roles configured in `~/.aws/config`, or `~/.aws/credentials`? Serverless looks in the latter, but it looks like your setup may be configured in the former? Def. looks like something to fix.

Comment: My Credentials are in the credentials file and roles are in the config file.  There is one set of credentials to many roles, as is permitted by AWS CLI.  This is the assumeRole setup to handle multiple accounts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

Comment: I solved with this, per a serverless github thread recommentation: https://github.com/remind101/assume-role

Comment: By setting the env var `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` it will load the named profiles in `~/.aws/config`. You can see more details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html#setting-region-config-file